# При вызове axios get запроса получаю пустой массив, когда в insomia все хорошо

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb, get, axios

```
export const getAfewProducts = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const products = await ProductModel.find({
      _id: { $in: req.body.items },
    });

    res.json(products);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({
      message: "Failed to get products",
    });
  }
};
```

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuth && isAuth.cart.length !== 0) {
      axios
        .get("/product/getAfew", {
          body: {
            items: isAuth.cart,
          },
        })
        .then((res) => {
          setData(res.data);
          console.log(res.data);
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }
  }, [isAuth]);
```

[image: запрос в incomnia, где все работает]